# How does powermetrics work?

Tags: macos, power, apple-silicon

Apple seems to have upgraded the output of `powermetrics` on M1 CPUs to include reports of consumed power. Output looks roughly like this:

```
sudo powermetrics  | grep -i power 
....   
E-Cluster Power: 230 mW
P0-Cluster Power: 3475 mW
P1-Cluster Power: 268 mW
ANE Power: 0 mW
DRAM Power: 1037 mW
CPU Power: 3973 mW
GPU Power: 125 mW
Package Power: 7348 mW
GPU Power: 125 mW
```

Is any of these reported powers actually measured, e.g. measured off of any of the voltage regulators? Or is it a case of a table look up, e.g. having a pre-characterized table of estimated power based on CPU/GPU core workloads the OS just returns a value?

What is included is Package Power? I would have expected that the sum NE+CPU+GPU+DRAM to be close to the total Package Power. Os that difference is caused by power for all the glue logic surrounding the CPU/GPU/NE and all IOs on the M1?